# paperclip - styles lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a script from which I load my rails environment. (

When I build an attachment and save its parent everything saves and gets created by the attachment style is always ["100>", "jpg"]

My Script:

```
require './config/environment.rb'
house = House.find(1)
house.attachments.build(doc: File.new('myfile.pdf'), category_id: 2)
house.save
```

Models

```
House < AR::Base
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end

Attachment < AR::Base
  ### has_attached_file :doc, styles: lambda {|attachment| {thumb: (attachment.instance.category_id == 2 ? ["500>", 'jpg'] : ['100>', 'jpg']} )}  
  has_attached_file :doc, styles: lambda {|attachment| {thumb: (attachment.instance.category_id == 2 ? ["500>", 'jpg'] : ['100>', 'jpg'] )}}  #category_id is always nil at this point but still still saves in the database 
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I'm guessing I've overlooked something silly here but I would appreciate any pointers :)

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax on that lambda looks a little funky.  I'm not sure how that ternary operator isn't barking an "unexpected ':'".

Give this a shot:

```
Attachment < AR::Base
  has_attached_file :doc, styles: lambda {|attachment| { thumb: (attachment.instance.category_id == 2 ? ["500>", 'jpg'] : ['100>', 'jpg'])}}
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: it was not a copy and paste job, I just mocked it up quick while I was away from my work computer.  I edited op.